# Two instance of SQL Server with same name?

Tags: sql-server

Can we have two DB instance on same server with same Database name in SQL server?

Comment: No. How do you think will it work? Name is ID of instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean two SQL Server "named instances" with each one containing a same "database" name, then yes.

On one server you could have two named instances:

- ServerName\InstanceA
- ServerName\InstanceB

Both InstanceA and InstanceB could each contain a database with name say "MyDatabase"

Answer (score 0):

No. You have to create same server with same Database name in SQL server
because SQL Server creates mdf or ldf file with physical location.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, different instances can have the same database name
Say
instanceA have DatabaseA with its datafile at location(D:DataFiles)
instanceB can have DatabaseA with its datafile pointed to another location(E:DataFiles)

If the above process is not followed it will be a mess

Thanks

- Installation of the new database